# New MySQL driver causes java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

If change MySQL JDBC driver from `5.1.38` to `6.0.2` I get the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
```

This exception was happened in normal JDBC initilization.

Probably, this can be related with SSL, since I get the following messages also

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

which were absent in previous version.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like a regression. Was there a particular reason to switch to 6.0.2? If not, I'd revert back to 5.1.38 and give 6.x a shot after three months to let folks at MySQL to stabilize the driver.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

It seems new versions of **mysql connector** *(from 6 on)* are not compatible with old version of the **DBMS mysql**(below 5.6). So in order to solve your problem, if you make an update of **mysql connector**, try to do the same **with the DBMS**. 
 Actually I had the same issu with *mysql connector 8.0.13* and the *DBMS msql 5.1....* I solved it by moving the *DBMS to 5.6.17*

Comment: As a result of incompatibility between version of the driver with the MySQL version installed. if you using springboot, you may need to change the version of the mysql driver to the one compartible with your Mysql DBMS. check answer by @P Satish Patro on this post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192560/spring-boot-client-plugin-auth-is-required

Comment: Had the same issue in PyCharm/Intellij IDEA. Just change Driver: MySQL to Driver: MySQL for 5.1

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I resolved by changing the parent tag version from 2.1.1.RELEASE to 2.0.0.RELEASE

from

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    Use Maven depandency 
###pom.xml  
           <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.37</version>
            </dependency>

##application.properties

server.port=9092
jwt.secret=javainuse
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to mysql version is too old so you need to do 3 changes in that case:
in application.properties do first 2 changes:

1. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`
2. `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
3. Do changes in pom.xml file in dependency of mysql-connector-java replace scope tag to the version tag and in version write your mysql version like  5.1

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this problem by removing mysql version in pom.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>       
</dependency>
```