# JDBC Connection Error With Maven

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem connecting to a database with JDBC. I get the following error upon connecting: `CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required`

Here is my code:

```
private void connect() {
  try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+url+":"+port+"/"+database, username, password);
    System.out.println(Messages.MYSQL_CONNECT_SUCCESS.toString());
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println(Messages.MYSQL_CONNECT_FAIL.toString()+e.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

Is my connection string wrong? This is what I added to my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I use this code (with different messages) in another project that does not use Maven, and it works fine. The credentials work. I've attempted to add `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: This may be caused by version `6.0.5` still having a few bumps, q.v. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348572/new-mysql-driver-causes-java-sql-sqlnontransientconnectionexception-client-plug

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Which version do you recommend then?

Comment: Try following what the link I gave says in the accepted answer.  If that doesn't fix it, then mention this and perhaps someone else has another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your  URL with the below and try it

```
jdbc:mysql://"+url+":"+port+"/"+database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false, username, password
```

This is related to SSL.